# Different way to create list within a list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a question about how to create a list within a list. For example, we use

```
[[0] * n for _ in range(m)]
```

to create a matrix with dimension `n*m`. However, when I tried the similar thing to create a nested list.

```
l = [[(0, 1)]] * n
```

And then update the `l[0]`, I find the `l[1]` would also get updated. However, the approach  `l = [[(0, 1)] for _ in range(n)]` produces what I need.

Would you please help me understand this issue?

Thanks for your help.

> Follow up:
> In the dynamic programming, we use [-math.inf]*n to construct a list and then update the values. Why this approach works, but the above approach failed? Thanks.

Comment: One multiplies the reference to the same list and puts it into your outer list n times - the other creates m independent new lists and adds them.

Comment: There's a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Thanks, @sj95126. I think that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Any part of Python I would go through to have a better understanding of this issue? Thanks, @PatrickArtner.

Answer (score 1):

The base list comprehension format

```
[0 for i in range(some_value)]
```

does create a `list` with `some_value` number of `0s`. Using `_` instead if `i` just discards it directly.
Now if you want a nested list, first question is, if outer list is rows or columns, however since most often it is `matrix[row][column]` i will go with it. So lets say you want 10 rows you need 10 items so

```
[row for i in range(number_rows)]
```

now what is your definition of a row

```
[0 for i in range(number_columns)]
```

if it is initialized with 0s.

Putting the two together, we get

```
columns, rows = 3,5
l = [[0 for i in range (columns)] for j in range(rows)]
```

EDIT:

Why `[[[0] * n] * m]` doesn't work:

When you multiply a mutable object, such as a list, it is not **copied**, but **referenced**, meaning, both list entries do point to the same variable in memory. The problem is referred to as *deep copy vs shallow copy*. It can be observed by calling `id` of an object.

```
l = [[1,2,3]]*3
Out[43]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

[id(i) for i in l]
Out[44]: [139708443372224, 139708443372224, 139708443372224]
```

As you can see, all items refer to the same variable, and hence, changing one changes all.

Comment: Would you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: sure give me a second :)

Comment: Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for editing. Might I ask why [[[0] * n] * m] won't work here?

Comment: The problem with the multiplier lies in the mutability of the list item, it is not copied, but referenced.

Comment: "When you multiply a mutable object, " well, it works that way for any object, to be clear

Comment: Thanks! Any part of Python I would go through to have a better understanding of this issue?

Comment: Mutable vs Immutable would be good start https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747, shallow and deep copy